# Building Design System on top of Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui in my project and had to customize Button and TexField and also wanted to extend the icons in material-ui for my needs.  My current solution is to use material-ui for all other needs and My custom Button, TextField and Icons wherever needed.

Current solution

```
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/core/Autocomplete'
import Add From '@material-ui/icons/Add'

import Button from 'my_package/core/Button'
import CustomIcon From 'my_package/icons/CustomIcom'
```

My desired solution is this

```
import Autocomplete from 'my_package/core/Autocomplete'
import Add From 'my_package/icons/Add'
import Button from 'my_package/core/Button'
import CustomIcon From 'my_package/core/DatePicker'
import CustomIcon From 'my_package/icons/CustomIcom'
```

my_package should internally use @material_ui.

i tried to add @material-ui as a dependency to my_package and in index.js i exported all material-ui components like this `export * from "@material-ui/core"`

This let's me import material-ui components from my_package like this

```
import { Autocomplete } from "my_package/core"
```

this is great but i loose tree shaking capability

what i need is this

```
import Autocomplete from "my_package/core/Autocomplete"
```

Basically i wanted to write a wrapper around @material-ui with tree shaking.  Is forking / cloning the material-ui the only way to do it. Button and Textfield is not the only component i want to customize.  What is the best practice to build a design system on top of material-ui?.

Thanks

Comment: How did you go? Did you find other design systems built on top of MUI?

Comment: any update on your end ? looking to find the better way too